# PasswordChangeForm from Django doesnt show on template with 2 forms

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-views

[image: So this is how it looks but it should show the form]
I'm tying to make a ChangePasswordForm but it isn't showing on template. The section only prints the description but it doesnt show the form. By the way, Ive been reading about that specific form, and most websites claim it to be implemented by Django, thats why i hadn't put it on forms. I think that might be the mistake. 
Update: I've add the first form, in this template am working with two forms but the first one is working normally, the problem its only on the second one.

**views.py**

```
def  profileedit_view(request):
form= PerfilEditadoForm(request.POST or None)
if request.method== 'POST':
    form.instance = request.user
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('profileedit')
    else:
        form= PerfilEditadoForm(instance=request.user)
        args= {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'profileedit.html', args)

context = {
    'form1': form
}
return render(request, "profileedit.html", context)
def change_password_view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        update_session_auth_hash(request, user)  # Important!
        messages.success(request, 'Contraseña cambiada con éxito')
        return redirect('profileedit')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Ha ocurrido un error.')
else:
    form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
context = {
    'form2': form
}
return render(request, 'profileedit.html', context)
```

**template (in case of)**

```
      <div class="tab-pane container p-0 active" id="home1">
                                  <form method="POST" action="#"> {% csrf_token %}
                                    <p>Por favor, no dejes ningún campo en blanco.
                                     <center> {{ form1.as_ul }}
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary py-1 px-2" type="submit" > Save </button>
                                    </center> </p>
                                    </form>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="tab-pane container p-0 fade" id="home2">
                                      <form method="POST" action="#"> {% csrf_token %}
                                          <p>  Por favor, escriba en los siguientes campos.
                                      <center> {{ form2.as_ul }}
                                              <button class="btn btn-primary py-1 px-2" type="submit" > Save </button></center></p></form>>
                                  </div>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path ('profileedit', profileedit_view, name='profileedit'),
path('profileedit', change_password_view, name='profileedit')] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

> here are two forms in the same template, but the first one its working normally

Comment: Is this view being served at that url? Can you share the urls?

Comment: yes, ill edit it

Comment: You are serving the `profileedit_view` at "/profileedit" as it is the first url pattern that matches. You shouldn't have both urls using the same path

Comment: how can i use both?

Comment: Do you want both forms in the same page? If so you need to have 1 view that handles both forms

Answer (score 0):

I think `{{ form2.as_ul }}` should be `{{ form.as_ul }}` in your template file.  You need to drop the "2" as that is the value you put in the context dict for key "form2".

Here's an example that I have running that returns 3 forms to one template using function based views:

```
    def home(request):
    """display app home page/landing page"""

    if request.method == 'POST':

        practiscore_url_form = PractiscoreUrlForm(request.POST)
        get_upped_form       = GetUppedForm(request.POST)
        accu_stats_form1     = AccuStatsForm1(request.POST)

        if practiscore_url_form.is_valid() and get_upped_form.is_valid() and accu_stats_form1.is_valid():

            return render(request, 'home.html', {
                'practiscore_url_form': practiscore_url_form,
                'get_upped_form'      : get_upped_form,
                'accu_stats_form1'    : accu_stats_form1,
                }
            )

    else:

        practiscore_url_form = PractiscoreUrlForm()
        get_upped_form       = GetUppedForm()
        accu_stats_form1     = AccuStatsForm1()


    return render(request, 'home.html', {
        'practiscore_url_form': practiscore_url_form,
        'get_upped_form'      : get_upped_form,
        'accu_stats_form1'    : accu_stats_form1,
        }
    )
```

Comment: Im using two forms in the same template, but first one its working normally

Comment: The views.py file you posted only has one form defined and being returned to your template.  You'll need to define a second form and return it as well to your template if you want a second form.

Comment: You have "form" defined twice within the same view now.  You need to give them unique variable names.